# how to solve "injection of autowired dependencies failed" issue?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I try to develop some server program. So, I test the program using junit4.
However suddenly injection of autowired dependencies failed error occurs.
I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me.

This is context-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="RDMLDBMgmt" class="kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml.RDMLDBMgmtImpl" />

</beans>
```

This is interface.

```
package kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;

import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.RDML;

public interface IRDMLDBMgmt {
    public boolean storeRDML(RDML rdml) throws RDMLDBException, RevisionControlException, RepositoryException, Exception ;
    public RDML retrieveRecentRDML(String id) throws RevisionControlException, Exception;
    public ArrayList<String> retrieveRDMLHistory(String id) throws RevisionControlException, Exception;
    public RDML retrieveRDML(String keyword) throws RDMLDBException, RepositoryException, Exception;
}
```

This is implementation code of interface.

```
package kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.NodeIterator;
import javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException;
import javax.jcr.Repository;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials;
import javax.jcr.UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException;
import javax.jcr.ValueFormatException;
import javax.jcr.query.Query;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryManager;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryResult;
import javax.jcr.version.Version;
import javax.jcr.version.VersionHistory;
import javax.jcr.version.VersionIterator;
import javax.jcr.version.VersionManager;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreController;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.RDML;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RDMLDBException;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RevisionControlException;

import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jdom2.Attribute;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RDMLDBMgmtImpl implements IRDMLDBMgmt {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SoremoreController.class.getName());
    static private int docNumber = 0;
    private Repository repository;
    private Session session;
    private Node root;
    private Node baseWP = null;
    private Node inputedWP = null;
    private List<String> remainedBaseWorkProductItemIds;
    private List<String> remainedInputedWorkProductItemIds;
    private VersionManager vm;
    private QueryManager queryManager;

    public RDMLDBMgmtImpl() throws ParserConfigurationException,
            UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException, RepositoryException {
        super();
        try {
            repository = JcrUtils.getRepository();
            session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin"
                    .toCharArray()));
            root = session.getRootNode();
            vm = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager();
            queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        remainedBaseWorkProductItemIds = new LinkedList<String>();
        remainedInputedWorkProductItemIds = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean storeRDML(RDML rdml) throws RDMLDBException,
            RevisionControlException, RepositoryException, Exception {
        Document rdmlAsDocument = rdml.getRdmlAsDocument();
        String id = rdml.getIdFromDocument(rdmlAsDocument);

        RDML curRdml = retrieveRecentRDML(id);
        if (curRdml != null && curRdml.getRdmlAsNode() != null)
            baseWP = curRdml.getRdmlAsNode();
        else
            baseWP = null;

        inputedWP = convertDocToNode(rdmlAsDocument, id);
        // version 정보 갱신
        if (baseWP == null) {
            initialVersioning(inputedWP);
        } else {
            versionUp();
        }

        return true;
    }

    // 수정필요 Node -> RDML 어떻게?
    // Node이름 가져올 수 있나????????
    @Override
    public RDML retrieveRecentRDML(String id) throws RevisionControlException,
            Exception {
        NodeIterator workproducts = root.getNodes("WorkProduct");
        Node workProduct = null;
        RDML rdml = new RDML();
        rdml.setRdmlID(id);

        while (workproducts.hasNext()) {
            workProduct = workproducts.nextNode();
            String rdmlID = workProduct.getProperty("jcr:id").getValue()
                    .getString();
            if (rdmlID.equals(id)) {
                rdml.setRdmlAsNode(workProduct);
                Document doc = convertNodeToDoc(workProduct);
                rdml.setRdmlAsDocument(doc);
                break;
            }
        }

        // RDML 반환
        return rdml;
    }

    // retrieveRecent 반환값 RDML로 바꾼 후 수정 필요
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> retrieveRDMLHistory(String id)
            throws RevisionControlException, Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> HistroyResult = new ArrayList<String>();

        Node curNode = convertDocToNode(retrieveRecentRDML(id)
                .getRdmlAsDocument(), id);
        VersionHistory history = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager()
                .getVersionHistory(curNode.getPath());
        VersionIterator versionIterator = history.getAllVersions();
        while (versionIterator.hasNext()) {
            Version version = (Version) versionIterator.next();
            String a = "version found : " + version.getName() + " - "
                    + version.getNode(version.getPath()).getName() + " - "
                    + version.getCreated().getTime();
            HistroyResult.add(a);
        }
        return HistroyResult;
    }

    public RDML retrieveRDML(String keyword) throws RDMLDBException,
            RepositoryException, Exception {
        String sql = "select * from [nt:base] where [jcr:content] = '"+keyword+"'";
        Query query = queryManager.createQuery(sql, Query.JCR_SQL2);
        QueryResult result  = query.execute();

        NodeIterator nodes = result.getNodes();
        while(nodes.hasNext()){
            Node node = nodes.nextNode();
            if(node.getProperty("jcr:id")!=null)
                System.out.println(node.getProperty("jcr:id").getString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String extractContent(Element element) throws Exception {
        String content = "";
        content = element.getValue();
        return content;
    }

    private List<Element> extractWorkProductItems(Document RD) {
        Element workProduct = RD.getRootElement();
        List<Element> workProductItems = workProduct
                .getChildren("WorkProductItem");
        return workProductItems;
    }

    private void initialVersioning(Node WorkProduct) throws Exception {
        WorkProduct.addMixin("mix:versionable");
        NodeIterator WorkProductItems = WorkProduct.getNodes("WorkProductItem");
        while (WorkProductItems.hasNext()) {
            Node WorkProductItem = WorkProductItems.nextNode();
            WorkProductItem.addMixin("mix:versionable");
        }
        session.save();
    }

    private void versionUp() throws Exception {
        NodeIterator WorkProductItems = inputedWP.getNodes("WorkProductItem");
        if (WorkProductItems == null) {
            workProductVersionUp();
        } else {
            workProductItemVersionUp();
        }
    }

    // If workproductItem is not exist, compare base workproduct's contents and
    // inputed workproduct's contents. Then change the version.
    private void workProductVersionUp() throws RepositoryException {
        String base = baseWP.getProperty("jcr:content").getValue().getString();
        String input = inputedWP.getProperty("jcr:content").getValue()
                .getString();
        if (base.equals(input)) {
            inputedWP.remove();
            System.out.println("recent workproduct version persist");

        } else {
            // ���
            if (baseWP.getProperty("jcr:deleted").getValue().getString()
                    .equals("false")) {
                vm.checkout(baseWP.getPath());
                baseWP.getProperty("jcr:content").setValue(input);
                session.save();
                vm.checkin(baseWP.getPath());
                inputedWP.remove();
                System.out.println("workproduct version is changed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("This workproduct has deleted");
            }
        }
    }

    private void workProductItemVersionUp() throws Exception {
        setAllBaseWorkProductItemId();
        setAllInputWorkProductItemId();

        vm.checkout(baseWP.getPath());
        NodeIterator inputWPIs = inputedWP.getNodes("WorkProductItem");
        while (inputWPIs.hasNext()) {
            Node inputWPI = inputWPIs.nextNode();

            // get inputed workproductItem's id
            String inputWPIid = inputWPI.getProperty("jcr:id").getValue()
                    .getString();

            // get inputed workproductItem's contents
            String inputWPIcontent = inputWPI.getProperty("jcr:content")
                    .getValue().getString();

            // get base workproductItem with same id
            Node baseWPI = getBaseWorkProductItem(inputWPIid, "WorkProductItem");

            // compare base workproductItem and inputed workproductItem
            if (baseWPI != null) {
                // get base workproductItem's contents
                String baseWPIcontent = baseWPI.getProperty("jcr:content")
                        .getValue().getString();

                // compare workproductItems contents.
                if (!isDeleted(baseWPI)) {
                    if (!inputWPIcontent.equals(baseWPIcontent)) {
                        vm.checkout(baseWPI.getPath());
                        baseWPI.getProperty("jcr:content").setValue(
                                inputWPIcontent);
                        session.save();
                        vm.checkin(baseWPI.getPath());
                        System.out.println(inputWPIid + "is changed");
                    }
                } else {
                    vm.checkout(baseWPI.getPath());

                    baseWPI.getProperty("jcr:deleted").setValue("false");
                    if (!inputWPIcontent.equals(baseWPIcontent)) {
                        baseWPI.getProperty("jcr:content").setValue(
                                inputWPIcontent);
                        System.out.println(inputWPIid
                                + "is undeleted and changed");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(inputWPIid + "is undeleted");
                    }

                    session.save();
                    vm.checkin(baseWPI.getPath());
                }

            }
        }
        addNodes("WorkProductItem");
        deleteNodes("WorkProductItem");
        inputedWP.remove();

        setAllBaseWorkProductItemId();
        session.save();
        vm.checkin(baseWP.getPath());
        System.out.println(baseWP.getPath() + " version = "
                + vm.getBaseVersion(baseWP.getPath()));
    }

    private Node getBaseWorkProductItem(String id, String nodeType)
            throws Exception {
        NodeIterator childNodes = baseWP.getNodes(nodeType);
        Node childNode = null;
        while (childNodes.hasNext()) {
            childNode = childNodes.nextNode();
            String childId = childNode.getProperty("jcr:id").getValue()
                    .getString();

            if (id.equals(childId)) {
                remainedBaseWorkProductItemIds.remove(childId);
                remainedInputedWorkProductItemIds.remove(childId);
                return childNode;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void setAllBaseWorkProductItemId() throws RepositoryException {
        NodeIterator baseWPIs = baseWP.getNodes("WorkProductItem");
        remainedBaseWorkProductItemIds.clear();
        while (baseWPIs.hasNext()) {
            Node baseWPI = baseWPIs.nextNode();
            remainedBaseWorkProductItemIds.add(baseWPI.getProperty("jcr:id")
                    .getValue().getString());
        }
    }

    private void setAllInputWorkProductItemId() throws RepositoryException {
        NodeIterator inputedWPIs = inputedWP.getNodes("WorkProductItem");
        remainedInputedWorkProductItemIds.clear();
        while (inputedWPIs.hasNext()) {
            Node inputedWPI = inputedWPIs.nextNode();
            remainedInputedWorkProductItemIds.add(inputedWPI
                    .getProperty("jcr:id").getValue().getString());
        }
    }

    private boolean isDeleted(Node node) throws Exception {
        boolean isDeleted = node.getProperty("jcr:deleted").getValue()
                .getString().equals("false");
        if (isDeleted) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void addNodes(String NodeType) throws Exception {
        Iterator<String> iter = remainedInputedWorkProductItemIds.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String WPIid = iter.next();
            NodeIterator nodes = inputedWP.getNodes(NodeType);
            Node node = null;
            boolean isMatch = false;
            while (nodes.hasNext()) {
                node = nodes.nextNode();
                String nodeId = node.getProperty("jcr:id").getValue()
                        .getString();
                if (nodeId.equals(WPIid)) {
                    isMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isMatch) {
                String nodeId = node.getProperty("jcr:id").getValue()
                        .getString();
                String nodeContent = node.getProperty("jcr:content").getValue()
                        .getString();

                if (!isDeleted(node)) {
                    Node newNode = baseWP.addNode(NodeType);
                    newNode.setProperty("jcr:id", nodeId);
                    newNode.setProperty("jcr:content", nodeContent);
                    newNode.setProperty("jcr:deleted", "false");
                    newNode.addMixin("mix:versionable");
                }
                System.out.println(nodeId + "is added");
            }
        }
    }

    private void deleteNodes(String NodeType) throws Exception {
        Iterator<String> iter = remainedBaseWorkProductItemIds.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String WPIid = iter.next();
            NodeIterator nodes = baseWP.getNodes(NodeType);
            Node node = null;
            boolean isMatch = false;
            while (nodes.hasNext()) {
                node = nodes.nextNode();
                String nodeId = node.getProperty("jcr:id").getValue()
                        .getString();
                if (nodeId.equals(WPIid)) {
                    isMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isMatch) {
                DeleteNode(node);
                System.out.println(node.getProperty("jcr:id").getValue()
                        .getString()
                        + "is deleted");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean DeleteNode(Node node) throws Exception {
        vm.checkout(node.getPath());
        node.getProperty("jcr:deleted").setValue("True");
        session.save();
        vm.checkin(node.getPath());
        return true;
    }

    private Document convertNodeToDoc(Node WorkProduct)
            throws ValueFormatException, IllegalStateException,
            PathNotFoundException, RepositoryException, IOException {
        Element rootElement = new Element("WorkProduct");
        Document doc = new Document(rootElement);
        // doc.setRootElement(rootElement);
        rootElement.setAttribute(new Attribute("ID", WorkProduct
                .getProperty("jcr:id").getValue().getString()));

        NodeIterator WorkProuctItems = WorkProduct.getNodes();
        while (WorkProuctItems.hasNext()) {
            Node WorkProcutItemNode = WorkProuctItems.nextNode();
            Element workProductItem = new Element("WorkProductItem");
            workProductItem.addContent(new Element("Content")
                    .setText(WorkProcutItemNode.getProperty("jcr:content")
                            .getValue().toString()));
            rootElement.addContent(workProductItem);
        }
        XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.output(doc,
                new FileWriter(new File("resource/Output_rdml/example_output"
                        + String.valueOf(++docNumber) + ".xml")));
        return doc;
    }

    private Node convertDocToNode(Document workProduct, String id)
            throws IllegalStateException, Exception {
        if (workProduct == null)
            return null;
        Node node = root.addNode("WorkProduct");
        node.setProperty("jcr:id", id);
        node.setProperty("jcr:deleted", false);
        List<Element> docWorkproductItems = extractWorkProductItems(workProduct);
        for (int i = 0; i < docWorkproductItems.size(); i++) {
            Element docWorkproductItem = docWorkproductItems.get(i);
            String workproductItemId = docWorkproductItem
                    .getAttributeValue("id");
            Node nodeWorkProductItem = node.addNode("WorkProductItem");
            nodeWorkProductItem.setProperty("jcr:deleted", false);
            nodeWorkProductItem.setProperty("jcr:id", workproductItemId);
            nodeWorkProductItem.setProperty("jcr:content",
                    extractContent(docWorkproductItems.get(i)));
        }
        return node;
    }

    public void sessionLogout() {
        session.logout();
    }
}
```

This is test code.

```
package kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.RDML;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RDMLDBException;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:soremore-servlet.xml" })
public class RDMLDBMgmtTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    IRDMLDBMgmt rdmlDBMgmt = null;

    @Test
    public void storeRDML() {
        ArrayList<RDML> rdmls = loadTestRDML();
        boolean isSuccessful = false;
        for (RDML rdml : rdmls) {
            try {
                isSuccessful = rdmlDBMgmt.storeRDML(rdml);
                System.out.println();
            } catch (RDMLDBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isSuccessful = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isSuccessful = false;
            }
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(isSuccessful);
    }

    @Test
    public void queryRDML0() {
        String[] rdmlIDs = { "RD01", "RD02" };
        boolean isSuccessful = false;

        for (String rdmlID : rdmlIDs) {
            try {
                isSuccessful = false;
                RDML rdml = rdmlDBMgmt.retrieveRecentRDML(rdmlID);
                if (rdml.getRdmlAsDocument() != null) {
                    Document doc = rdml.getRdmlAsDocument();
                    if (doc != null) {
                        isSuccessful = true;
                    }
                }
                Assert.assertTrue(isSuccessful);
            } catch (RDMLDBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void queryRDML1(){
        String[] keywords = { "연구", "RD" };
        boolean isSuccessful = false;

        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            try {
                isSuccessful = false;
                RDML rdml = rdmlDBMgmt.retrieveRDML(keyword);
                if (rdml.getRdmlAsDocument() != null) {
                    Document doc = rdml.getRdmlAsDocument();
                    if (doc != null) {
                        isSuccessful = true;
                    }
                }
                Assert.assertTrue(isSuccessful);
            } catch (RDMLDBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<RDML> loadTestRDML() {
        ArrayList<RDML> rdmls = new ArrayList<RDML>();
        String xmlSource = "resource/sample_rdml";

        File sourceDir = new File(xmlSource);
        File[] sourceFiles = sourceDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : sourceFiles) {
            RDML rdml = new RDML();
            rdml.setRdmlAsDocument(createDocument(file));
            rdmls.add(rdml);
        }

        return rdmls;
    }

    private Document createDocument(File rdmlPathAsFile) {
        SAXBuilder jdomBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document jdomDocument = null;
        try {
            jdomDocument = jdomBuilder.build(rdmlPathAsFile);
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jdomDocument;
    }
}
```

finally this is error stack.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml.RDMLDBMgmtTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml.RDMLDBMgmtTest.rdmlDBMgmt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml.RDMLDBMgmtTest.rdmlDBMgmt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Where is `soremore-servlet.xml` file? Are you sure you declare a bean of class `RDMLDBMgmtImpl` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem which is see from code is , you have created bean twice for implementation `RDMLDBMgmtImpl`. Once with XML mapping as :

```
<bean id="RDMLDBMgmt" class="kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml.RDMLDBMgmtImpl" />
```

And second, you have used the `@Service` annotation on class `RDMLDBMgmtImpl`.

Remove the bean mapping from XML or remove the annotation. Also add `context:annotation-config`  for making `@Autowired`  annotation to work.

Cannot add a comment because of low reputation points.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you help me one more? I remove bean mapping from XML and add <context:annotation-config /> in XML. However, still same error occurs. Do you know that?

Comment: I created `config` folder in `src/resources` and copied `soremore-servlet.xml` . The classpath is like `config/soremore-servlet.xml`.  Modified the @ContextConfiguration like '@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/soremore-servlet.xml" })' and it worked for me.  Please try this. Hope this might work for you as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.